# Getting a Mapping Parser Error for a Date Field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

When I try to update a document with a date field, I get this error. This does not occur 100% of the time and if I add the document using kibana with the same timestamp, it works.

`RequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', "failed to parse field [mem_data.time_start] of type [date] in document with id '8914cbb265aa11ebb145acbc32b9f8b7'. Preview of field's value: '2021-02-02 20:44:05.995401'")`

This is my mapping for the time_start field

````
            "type":"date",
            "format":"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
         }```
````

Comment: Can you provide more details ? You have mentioned that from kibana it is working fine, from which client is failing? Is it possible to provide request payload ?

Comment: It is failing using elasticsearch_dsl using the update function, I have the same date format when I define the persistence layer for the time_start,